# How does "for in" loop work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

The program is as follows,

```
function sum(x) {
  console.log(typeof x[0]); //return Number
  var s=0;
  for(var e in x) {
    console.log(typeof e); //This return string
    s+=e;
  }
  return s;
}
console.log(sum([1,2,3,4,5])); //return 001234
```

If I use a number constructor then it works fine.

```
function sum(x) {
      console.log(typeof x[0]); // return Number
      var s=0;
      for(var e in x) {
        s+=Number(e);
      }
      return s;
    }
    console.log(sum([1,2,3])); //return 6
```

What is happening at `for in` loop?

Comment: `for in` Loops over an Array and stores the value in and other variable

Comment: for in loops over all the properties of an object. Since index are proeprties of an array object, you 'simulate' a basic for loop here. But you should not use for in on arrays. It's meant to be used for objects, sicne if you set any other properties onto the array, they will get found by for in as well, ( `s.prop = 'someprop'` ) Use a basic for-loop or `s.forEach()` instead.

Comment: first is string append `s+=e;`  and in second is sum  `s+=Number(e);`

Comment: do you realize you are not adding up the values of your array but the proerty names? `var x = [5,6,7]
for(var e in x) console.log(e, typeof e)`

Comment: @epascarello I just checked. I got it

Comment: What is the reason of negative voting?

Comment: But it is how for-each picks up the properties. Coming from [Java](https://blog.udemy.com/for-each-loop-java/) it is easy to take it granted.

Comment: Yes ofcourse `reduce` is even better, but in my experience the people asking about for .. in only get confused when starting the whole array methods learning, so starting with forEach and rewriting the for loop first and then working towarths reduce, worked better for me to explain to people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others have already pointed out that for-in iterates over properties, not values. In the case of an array the properties are the indices.

```html
function sum(x) {
  var s=0;
  for(var e in x) {
    s+=e;
  }
  return s;
};
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
array.b="z";
console.log(sum(array)); // prints 001234b
```

In the resulting 001234b string you have:
Leading "0": The initial value of s
Then "0" because first index is 0
Then "1", etc

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in original insertion order.

and

> A different property name is assigned to variable on each iteration.

Property names are strings. So you get strings. The `+` operator will concatenate strings.

If you convert the value to a number, then you don't have strings any more. The `+` operator will perform addition on numbers.

---

> ```
> console.log(sum([1,2,3]); //return 6
> ```

No.

It throws an error because you have one `)` too few. If you fix that, it outputs `3` because you are looping over the *property names* not the values, so you are adding `0`, `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 1):

For ... in loop in es6 is used to loop over objects.

As an array is technically an object it loops over the index of the array. You can see this by console.logging inside the for loop.

Use For ... of loop to loop over arrays normally.

```
function sum(x) {
  console.log(typeof x[0]); //return Number
  var s=0;
  for(var e of x) {  // of loop
    console.log(e)
    s+=e;
  }
  return s;
}
console.log(sum([1,2,3,4,5])); //return 001234
```